# PHP+cURL+POST not working

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I'm trying to make a post request a site but it's not working.

I've made that POST request using Postman (Chrome extension) and it works fine.

The url I'm trying to get is something like: https://scanurl.net/?u=google.com

My code is:

```
    <?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $postvars = [
    'u' => 'google.com'
    ];

  $url = "https://scanurl.net/";

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);                //0 for a get request
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  print "curl response is:" . $response;
  curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Solution (using POSTMAN code snippets:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$url='https://scanurl.net/?u=gxxoe.com';
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 // CURLOPT_URL => "https://scanurl.net/?u=gxoe.com",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: be8b2f15-e8fd-86f9-5d7a-01f4b4b79587"
  ),
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

?>
```

Comment: what's the error ? and what do you expect from the request ?

Comment: I don't get anything. I expect to get what this website has: https://scanurl.net/?u=google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely worked in Postman because you were setting GET variables rather than POST variables which are different. I've modified the code above to something that should work:

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  $url = "https://scanurl.net/";

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url.'?u=google.com');
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  print "curl response is:" . $response;
  curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Edit: I should add, make sure that you check with the website owner before doing this often, as they may not take kindly to people scraping information from their website.

Comment: As you can see, it's a POST form:<form action="https://scanurl.net/index.php" target="_top" method="post" name="uef" class="uef" style="" align="center" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<input type="text" name="u" id="u" class="ueti" style="" size="55" maxlength="450" value="" title="Enter URL to check..." tabindex="1">

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided? I tested it before posting :)

Comment: using postman and curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) , I've solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a curl-request out of Postman directly, but keep in mind that there is a little bug:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2631

You have to add the parameter `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` with the value `POST` and then have to add your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score 0):

try this it's slow will take 3-5 mins cause redirect  but should get the data back.

```
$url = "https://scanurl.net/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "u=google.com");   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded",'Content-Length: ' . strlen("u=google.com")  )  );
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```